# How to determine that a certain result is statistically significant?

Tags: statistics

I know no to little statistics and trying to interpret a result whether statistically significant or not. I am given a 'Confidence interval' and here's the exact context: "increased intake of 100 g/d of fruit and vegetables was associated with a significantly decreased prevalence of current smokers (-3.1%; 95% CI: -3.9, -2.4)".
Now by a bit of googling, I came to know that if p-value is less than or equal to the significance level (which would be 0.05), then it is statistically significant. But I am not given a p-value! So is there a way to judge the significance given only the CI? What am I missing?
Please help!

Comment: If your 95% confidence interval does not contain 0, then your result  is statistically significant at the 5%  level. If you're interested in learning more, you want to read into "hypothesis testing" and its relationship to confidence intervals.

Comment: The phrase "Statistically significant" unaccompanied by numbers (see the comment above) is not  mathematically definable. In descriptions of practical research, whether this phrase is appropriate depends strongly on the context.  For  a headful of this, look at some of the articles on SciencBasedMedicine.Org